# How to make gif play inside a popup once popup is appended to page with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Writing a small extension that once an anchor tag is clicked, the link is turned into regular text and a popup box comes up. Once this happens, a gif is supposed to autoplay inside the popup box, however, I see the stock 'image hasn't loaded' image once the popup box is animated in. My popup box element is appened through JQuery on click. I've tried setting the attr() to the filepath and using 'background-image' in CSS as well.

Javascript:

```
var counter = 0;

$(function() {
  $("a").on("click", togglePopup);
});

function togglePopup() {
  var popup = '<div class="popup"><img id="gif" src="boom.gif"/></div>';

  counter++; 

  if (counter === 2) {
    counter = 0;
    $(".popup").remove();
  }

  if ($(this).children(".popup").length > 0) {
    $(".popup").slideFadeToggle();
  } else {
    $(this)
      .attr("href", null)
      .css({
        "text-decoration": "none",
        color: "#333"
      });
    $(this).append(popup);
    $(".popup").slideFadeToggle();
  }
}

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function() {
  return this.animate({ height: "toggle" }, "fast");
};
```

CSS:

```
.popup {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: default;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 25px 25px 20px;
}
```

Comment: check your console / network inspector, your image is probably 404 not found, use absolute url `src="/boom.gif"` instead of `src="boom.gif"`

Comment: where did you store you image i tried the code added a gif and its working